# How can I configure the kafka connect handler in OGG for Hdfs

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, oracle-golden-gate

I am doing a POC on moving data from Oracle db to Hadoop file system using Kafka(new at this). I have configured my extract on oracle db and it publishes the changes done in my source table to my kafka handler consumer and I can see the data on my topic. Now i want to do the same on a kafka connect handler and i want the schema and data on a file in my hdfs . I know i can configure the kafka handler to read my extract trail files. But where do i put the details of my target hdfs so that kafka can dump data into hdfs?

Comment: Also i am doing this using Goldengate

Comment: Wait. I guess i am wrong in assuming that kafka will do the dump. it just displays what it gets right? so i have to build a consumer for hdfs which will read the data on the kafka topic and do the writing to my hdfs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stream from Oracle to Kafka using the OGG Kafka Connect handler. Examples [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/streaming-data-oracle-using-oracle-goldengate-kafka-connect/) and [here](https://rmoff.net/2018/02/01/howto-oracle-goldengate-apache-kafka-schema-registry-swingbench/). There's also a Kafka handler if you want. [More details here](https://rmoff.net/2018/12/12/streaming-data-from-oracle-into-kafka-december-2018/).
2. Stream from Kafka to HDFS using [kafka-connect-hdfs](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-hdfs/)